# Display error in FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, version-10, frame

I want to make 2D plot with manually available `FrameTicks`.

In the case of using `FrameTicks` with automatic setting,

```
ListPlot[{{10, 0.48}, {35, 0.80}, {55, 1.34}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 2}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}]
```

[image]

The vertical axis of the result shows `{0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0}`. It's OK.

---

However, in the case of using designated `FrameTicks`,

```
 ListPlot[{{10, 0.48}, {35, 0.80}, {55, 1.34}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 2}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 50, 10], Range[0, 2, 0.5], None, None}]
```

[image]

The vertical axis of the result shows `{0.,0.5,1.,1.5,2.}`.

The difference between them is integer representation, for example, `0` shows `"0.0"` or `"0."`. 
Why is it happened? And, could you give me a solution?

Or, could you give me a way to erase minor ticks (subsidiary scale mark)?

Comment: I get same result for both on version 11.2 on windows 7. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qBRMv.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using version 10.0 on Win7-64bit.

Comment: In this case, it looks like something that was fixed in later versions? I tried it on 10.3 also on win7 and it works there. Do not have version 10.0 to try.

Comment: Yes, I think too. I have version 7.0 and it works same as ver. 10.0.